# I need software to help know the number cells present in my battery

Tags: laptop, battery, cells

Is there any software I can use to get a comprehensive information about my battery ie the number of cells because I read somewhere that the more cells the battery has the longer the charge lasts, I need to know the number of cells on mine so I upgrade to a battery with more cells to give me a duration of 8 hours and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about it backwards. It's true that cars have more wheels than bikes. It's also true that cars can fit more people than bikes. But if you want to check if your family will fit in a vehicle, you shouldn't be counting the wheels.

Compare battery capacity. It's measured in `mWh` or `Wh` (1 Wh = 1000 mWh). The bigger capacity, the longer the battery will last.

Comment: How do I check the battery capacity, is there a software I can use to get that without unplugging the battery, its not charging right now and am so far from a jack pin wall

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU Yes, there's plenty of programs that will report it. Google will certainly help you find something that will work. I think even Windows's built in battery health report contains it.

Comment: Yes I did and it worked, it generated a html report. I used this command ***powercfg /batteryreport***

Comment: It says the capacity is ***34,084 mWh***.  How do I calculate the life from that?

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU Note that it's the current estimated capacity, not the original capacity of a brand new battery. Battery life depends on how much energy the laptop will be drawing from the battery, which depends on its specs and how you use it. The battery report you've generated should contain estimates based on typical usage and historical lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as that.

First of all a battery built into a device is limited by space. So only this many cells can fit into the same space

Apart from that:

The number of cells in series determine the batteries voltage. The number of cells in parallel determine the batteries capacity and maximum output amperage.

For example a battery with 3 cells in series and 4 in parallel (3S4P), with 2000mAh capacity per cell, will have a voltage of `4,2V * 3 = 12,6V` and a capacity of `2000mAh * 4 = 8000mAh = 8Ah`

To visualize it, this circuit with 3 cells in series would have 36V 1A
[image: series batteries]

While this circuit with 3 batteries in parallel would have 12V 3A
[image: parallel batteries]

(image source: digikey)

You could theoretically change the number of cells in parallel, which in turn would result in a higher capacity pack, but you can't simply change the number of cells in series because; 1. The voltage would change and 2. you would need a different Battery Management System (BMS).

It might be better to get a second battery if it is user changeable, or get a notebook power bank. There are models with USB-C, some with adjustable DC output and a barrel connector and even some with a 110V/230V AC outlet.

Comment: But I want to believe there is a higher capacity battery replacement for this laptop model ***HP 348 G4***

Comment: Most of the higher capacity packs come with wrong ratings from the manufacturer. Your best bet is buying a original HP replacement. It seems like your model has a replacable battery anyways, so it is easy to get a second pack.

Comment: I just checked Amazon and there is a replacement for this model battery with a higher capacity ***47wh***, and its because its got more cells *6 cells*, it makes you want to revisit your post?

Comment: There is a voltage warning though ***This battery is not compatible with the battery voltage 14.6V and 14.8V.***, does this mean it won't work on my system?

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU I definitely don't want to revisit my post, my statements stand correct. The 6 cell battery packs are a scam. Your notebooks battery pack has 4 cells in series, resulting in the voltage of 14,4V. Your notebook cannot run on a different battery voltage and it is impossible to setup cells in a imbalanced parallel configuration without a thermal runaway, From the formfactor and the length of the pack (275mm) it looks like it fits 4 18650 cells (4 * 65mm = 260mm).